# I need to work it like <jsp:forward page="page_path"/> but using javascriptIs there any javascript function to forward to another page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I know how to redirect from a jsp page using Javascript.
But How can I forward using Javascript. Any function available ?

I need to work it like

```
<jsp:forward page="page_path"/>
```

but using javascript. I can not use *window.location.href* or *window.location.replace* as both of these actually redirect, not forward.

Thanks

Comment: -1, you haven't at least once tried to google it, [e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I do not know why people giving me negative ranking for this question without giving me right answer !! everybody giving answer of redirecting not forwarding.

Comment: Because you can not do that from javascript, see my answer. I have removed my downvote since the question is legit, though it did not seem so. I advise you to read the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next question :)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen your answer. I wanted not redirect as forwarding is lighter than redirection. But I find it is troublesome and not possible actually.

Comment: You are welcome, yes, that is not possible. Maybe [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) will suit your needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java practices site](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181) sums it up nicely:

> Forward
>
> - a forward is **performed internally by the servlet**
> - the **browser is completely unaware that it has taken place**, so its original URL remains intact
> - any browser reload of the resulting page will simple repeat the original request, with the original URL
>
> Redirect
>
> - a redirect is a two step process, where the web application instructs the browser to fetch a second URL, which differs from the original
> - a browser reload of the second URL will not repeat the original request, but will rather fetch the second URL
> - redirect is marginally slower than a forward, since it requires two browser requests, not one
> - objects placed in the original request scope are not available to the second request

Forward happens *while* processing on the server,so you can not invoke it with JS, since JS execution is happening *while* processing client-side.

The only option I see is to redirect to the same URL, but append a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameter to instruct the server to perform a forward this time. However, that will reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried-

**window.history.forward()**

it will work if there is next URL in the history list.

Comment: it will not work if nothing is in browser history to forward. right ? I have tried right now.

Comment: yes, where some one can go if you are already at end of the road

Comment: I need to work it like <jsp:forward page="page_path"/> but using javascript

Comment: sorry i am not aware if jsp's, but what i see here this will redirect the request, tell me from where you want to pull next page server or client machine ?

Comment: I actually want to forward to a page if a client selects a radio button.

Comment: then you are in wrong direction here, there is no way to get next page without hitting server, only history pages from browser can be accessed

Answer (score -1):

Just call:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: I think it is redirecting, not forwarding